# Im getting ArgumentOutOfRange exception when trying to color text in a listBox why?

Tags: c#, winforms

This is the class :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace GatherLinks
{
    class ColorText
    {


        public static void Texts(RichTextBox box, string text, Color color)
        {
            box.SelectionStart = box.TextLength;
            box.SelectionLength = 0;

            box.SelectionColor = color;
            box.AppendText(text);
            box.SelectionColor = box.ForeColor;
        }

        public static void ColorListBox(List<string> data, DrawItemEventArgs e)
        {
            string strLeft = null;
            string strMid = "---";
            string strRight = null;
            if (data[e.Index].Contains(strMid))
            {
                int index = data[e.Index].IndexOf(strMid);
                strLeft = data[e.Index].Substring(0, index);
                strRight = data[e.Index].Substring(index + strMid.Length);
            }

            using (Font f = new Font(FontFamily.GenericSansSerif, 16, FontStyle.Regular))
            {
                float startPos;
                e.Graphics.DrawString(strLeft, f, Brushes.Red, e.Bounds.X, e.Bounds.Y);
                startPos = e.Graphics.MeasureString(strLeft, f).Width;
                e.Graphics.DrawString(strMid, f, Brushes.Black, e.Bounds.X + startPos, e.Bounds.Y);
                startPos = e.Graphics.MeasureString(strLeft + strMid, f).Width;
                e.Graphics.DrawString(strRight, f, Brushes.Green, e.Bounds.X + startPos, e.Bounds.Y);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Im using the ColorListBox method.

In Form1 i have:

```
private void listBox1_DrawItem(object sender, DrawItemEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Index == -1)
            {
            }
            else
            {

                ColorText.ColorListBox(data, e);

            }
        }
```

Now when the exception is show up:

I see that the variable data is `count = 0`
The exception is on this line:

```
if (data[e.Index].Contains(strMid))

Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection

System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException was unhandled
  HResult=-2146233086
  Message=Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
Parameter name: index
  Source=mscorlib
  ParamName=index
  StackTrace:
       at System.ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentOutOfRangeException()
       at System.Collections.Generic.List`1.get_Item(Int32 index)
       at GatherLinks.ColorText.ColorListBox(List`1 data, DrawItemEventArgs e) in d:\C-Sharp\HardwareMonitoring\HardwareMonitoring\Hardwaremonitoring\ColorText.cs:line 29
       at HardwareMonitoring.Form1.listBox1_DrawItem(Object sender, DrawItemEventArgs e) in d:\C-Sharp\HardwareMonitoring\HardwareMonitoring\Hardwaremonitoring\Form1.cs:line 394
       at System.Windows.Forms.ListBox.OnDrawItem(DrawItemEventArgs e)
       at System.Windows.Forms.ListBox.WmReflectDrawItem(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.ListBox.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
       at System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.SendMessage(HandleRef hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.SendMessage(Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ReflectMessageInternal(IntPtr hWnd, Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmOwnerDraw(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmDrawItem(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.ScrollableControl.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.ContainerControl.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Form.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
       at System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.CallWindowProc(IntPtr wndProc, IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
       at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DefWndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.DefWndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.ListBox.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
  InnerException:
```

How can i fix it so it won't throw this exception again ? Is that since i never send any info to the data variable so it's `count = 0` and that's why the exception show up ?

Thanks in advance.

EDIT*

This is the backgroundworker dowork event in Form1:

```
private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            BackgroundWorker worker = sender as BackgroundWorker;
            while (true)
            {

                if ((worker.CancellationPending == true))
                {
                    e.Cancel = true;
                    break;
                }
                else
                {
                    if (tempCpuValue >= (float?)nud1.Value || tempGpuValue >= (float?)nud1.Value)
                    {
                        soundPlay = true;
                        NudgeMe();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        soundPlay = false;
                        stop_alarm = true;

                    }

                    tempCpuValue = Core.cpuView(pauseContinueDoWork,cpu,this,data,tempCpuValue,button1);
                    tempGpuValue = Core.gpuView(pauseContinueDoWork,data,tempGpuValue,button1);
                    this.Invoke(new Action(() => data = new List<string>()));
                    tempCpuValue = Core.cpuView(pauseContinueDoWork, cpu, this, data, tempCpuValue, button1);
                    tempGpuValue = Core.gpuView(pauseContinueDoWork, data, tempGpuValue, button1);
                    this.Invoke(new Action(() => listBox1.DataSource = null));
                    this.Invoke(new Action(() => listBox1.DataSource = data));



                    //listBox1.DataSource = data;

                }
            }
        }
```

I can't find anywhere where do i add or put something into the List 
Also when i'm running my program the listBox is empty.

Could be this is the reason for the exception since data is empty and also when im doing listBox1.DataSource = data so in fact the listBox is empty ?

Comment: `e.Index` is out of range. From the documentation: `This property can return -1 if items were removed from the list.` Was something removed?

Comment: It only happened when listbox items count not match with "data" list count, problem is listbox having more items than "data" list.

Comment: Chris i found now that i never added/put anything to the data variable in Form1 and also that the listBox is empty. Edited my question. Could be this is the reason ? And if it does how should i handle in a case where the variable data is empty ? Nothing removed i checked it's just i never add/put anything to the variable data or the listBox.

Comment: asharajay the only place i put something to the listBox is in the dowork event ( edited my question ) and it seems that both listBox and the data are empty.

Comment: @user2760148 check my answer! hope it works!!

Comment: I found now when the exception is happen. When i run the program in the listNox there are two items but once i move the mouse over the listBox window/area and then click the mouse left button the exception happen. And i don't have any listBox mouse down event. Strange.

Comment: I used a breakpoint now and saw that this.Invoke(new Action(() => listBox1.DataSource = data)); both data and listBox1.DataSource contain two items. The exception happen only when i put the mouse pointer over the listBox1 area and then click the mouse left button.

Comment: The question is if the solution still should be with the e.index and the data variables or something with to avoid somehow from the user to click over the listBox area ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check count of List before checking index value.

```
if (data.Count > e.Index)
{
    if (data[e.Index].Contains(strMid))
    {
        int index = data[e.Index].IndexOf(strMid);
        strLeft = data[e.Index].Substring(0, index);
        strRight = data[e.Index].Substring(index + strMid.Length);
    }

}
```

Comment: `Count > 0` not going to help. Supposed to be `data.Count > e.Index`

Answer (score 1):

Please use following code instead of yours..

```
private void listBox1_DrawItem(object sender, DrawItemEventArgs e)
{
   if (e.Index >=0 )
   {
      ColorText.ColorListBox(listBox1.Items.Cast<string>().ToList(), e);
   }
}
```

or still you get an error change ColorListBox method with following code:

```
public static void ColorListBox(List<string> data, DrawItemEventArgs e)
{
    string strLeft = null;
    string strMid = "---";
    string strRight = null;
    if (e.Index < data.Count)
    {
        if (data[e.Index].Contains(strMid))
        {
            int index = data[e.Index].IndexOf(strMid);
            strLeft = data[e.Index].Substring(0, index);
            strRight = data[e.Index].Substring(index + strMid.Length);
        }

        using (Font f = new Font(FontFamily.GenericSansSerif, 16, FontStyle.Regular))
        {
            float startPos;
            e.Graphics.DrawString(strLeft, f, Brushes.Red, e.Bounds.X, e.Bounds.Y);
            startPos = e.Graphics.MeasureString(strLeft, f).Width;
            e.Graphics.DrawString(strMid, f, Brushes.Black, e.Bounds.X + startPos, e.Bounds.Y);
            startPos = e.Graphics.MeasureString(strLeft + strMid, f).Width;
            e.Graphics.DrawString(strRight, f, Brushes.Green, e.Bounds.X + startPos, e.Bounds.Y);
        }
    }
}
```